# How to set the height of a textfield widget in KivyMD

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

How to set exactly not the maximum height, but the default height, that is, the vertical size of the widget? Шf you do exactly as with the width then nothing will work

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are asking.
In KivyMD MDTextField is just a line with a hint_text(If you give).
What do you mean by increasing the height of a line?

You can increase the font size of input like this.

```
        MDTextField:
            hint_text:"Enter UserName"
            pos_hint:{'center_x':.5,'center_y':.5}
            font_size:"36dp"
```

or are you looking for rectangle mode?

```
       MDTextField:
            hint_text:"Enter UserName"
            mode:"rectangle"
            pos_hint:{'center_x':.5,'center_y':.5}
            font_size:"18dp"
```

or you can use:

```
       MDTextFieldRect:
            hint_text:"Enter Name"
            pos_hint:{'center_x':.5,'center_y':.2}
            size_hint:1,None
            height:"50dp"
```

Comment: I want it to look like this:  max_height: -110 ,but if the max_height value is negative, the widget does not work.